# How to use ECDsa

Tags: c#, .net, ecdsa, elliptic-curve, key-pair

I'm creating a tool that generates EC key pair. I'm new to the Elliptic Curve Algorithm. I started with this function:

```
public static void GenerateECPublicKey(byte[] p, byte[] g, byte[] a, byte[] b, byte[] x, byte[] y)
{
            byte[] cofactor = Utilities.HexStringToByteArray("0000");

            ECCurve curve = new ECCurve() {Prime = p, Order = g, A = a, B = b, G = new ECPoint() { X = x, Y = y },
                CurveType = ECCurve.ECCurveType.PrimeShortWeierstrass, Cofactor = cofactor};

            ECDsa ec = ECDsaCng.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);
            ec.GenerateKey(curve);
}
```

The problem is I'm having an exception:  "Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Unknown error (0xc0000001)'". Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about this exception and what is causing the issue. Am I missing some components on the ECCurve?

Thank you in advance for the one who can help.

Comment: Is P and M prime?  See Wiki article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography